# Match multiple lines until a string contains

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have an csv file which contains the following information and I need the regular expression matching with the string as 'B08-1506' starting point until the next pattern matching with the above string. And I want to append the three lines to be considered as a single line

```
B08-1506,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B08-1606,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B09-0680,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B09-0681,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
```

Output should be like this,

```
B08-1506,324873, st, $0.0,ljkflka,jksdfhjfhjk,jkdsfh
B08-1606,324873, st, $0.0,ljkflka,jksdfhjfhjk,jkdsfh
B09-0680,324873, st, $0.0,ljkflka,jksdfhjfhjk,jkdsfh
B09-0681,324873, st, $0.0,ljkflka,jksdfhjfhjk,jkdsfh
```

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with CSV generation because those fields containing new lines should have been contained in double quotes. You are probably better off fixing that problem rather than finding a workaround using regexes.

Comment: Are you sure you need a regular expression? Will the B##-#### always be the first thing on the line? Are you familar with split()   

http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

Comment: Fix the CSV at the first place. If you are not able to do it and need a workaround [`r"(?<=\d{2}\-\d{4}).*?(?=B\d{2}\-\d{4})|(?<=\d{2}\-\d{4}).*"sg`](https://regex101.com/r/pCReQ0/2) would work for you

Comment: I have edited my csv file, @AniketSahrawat the above reg expression picking the lines upto the numerical values not the alphabets

Comment: **[It is working](https://regex101.com/r/pCReQ0/3)**

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yeah thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like **Nisarg** said it is best to fix the source csv format. But incase you are not able to the below snippet might help.

**Demo:**(*Without Regex*)

```
s = """B08-1506,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B08-1606,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B09-0680,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,
B09-0681,324873, st, $0.0,
ljkflka,,,,,
1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjk
jkdsfh,,,,,,,"""

res = []
for i in s.split("\n"):
    if i.startswith("B0"):    #Check if line starts with "B0"
        res.append(i)
    else:                      #else concat to the previous element in res. 
        res[-1] = res[-1]+i

res = [filter(None, i.split(",")) for i in res]    #Filter to remove all empty elements
for i in res:
    print(", ".join(i))
```

**Output:**

```
B08-1506, 324873,  st,  $0.0, ljkflka, 1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjkjkdsfh
B08-1606, 324873,  st,  $0.0, ljkflka, 1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjkjkdsfh
B09-0680, 324873,  st,  $0.0, ljkflka, 1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjkjkdsfh
B09-0681, 324873,  st,  $0.0, ljkflka, 1 of 37 jksdfhjfhjkjkdsfh
```

Comment: this would fall over if the first line of the file didn't begin with "B0".  Could check `elif res` instead of `else`.

Comment: @Constance. The OP states all of the lines start with "B0".

Comment: Checking `if res` would fail after the first loop.

Comment: I understand that all the lines start with "B0", but it wasn't clear that the first line was at the *very* start of the file, maybe there are header lines at the top which need to be skipped.

Comment: In that case you can use list slicing to filter the headers.